# Pgfplots axis, option to remove (or ignore) legends

Tags: pgfplots, legend

Is there an option in `pgfplots` at the `axis` level or a setting of `legend style` option, that would effectively ignore the subsequent legend entries in the plot?

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend style = {at={(1.03,-0.03)}},
        %ignore legend %hypothetical option
    ]
    \addlegendentry{graph 1} %ignored
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=none,forget plot] {0.1*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{graph 2} %ignored
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=red,line legend] {0.1*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{graph 3} %ignored
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=blue,line legend] {0.0*x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```

I have a large plot (many curves) and I want to remove all the legends at the same time, without modifying the code too much.

Comment: As a quick hack you can skip all the `\addlegendentry` commands by assigning it to `\relax`. So put `every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}` to the hypothetical line and it will locally cancel all the legend entries.

Comment: @percusse, yes, I was looking for a hack like this. However when I add your option, the whole text for legends appears in text mode before a plot with no legends.

Comment: Strange I don't see anything. I'm using v1.6.

Comment: @percusse: Your suggestion seems to work just fine for me as well. I am not able to reproduce the problem that alfC experiences with your approach.

Comment: @PeterGrill Maybe it's a better idea to gobble the argument too to avoid those cases (though I can't replicate it) but I'll wait in case Christian chips in.

Comment: @percusse: That's exactly the problem I thought the OP was experiencing, but was not able to reproduce it.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Is this a valid hack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what can be done for your problem.

**Option 1**

As suggested by percusse `every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}` can be used to suppress legends. Following code shows their use both locally and globally.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}} %%%if you don't want them globally, uncomment this line

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend style = {at={(1.03,-0.03)}},
     every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}   %ignore legend locally 
    ]
    \addlegendentry{graph 1} %ignored
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=none,forget plot] {0.1*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{graph 2} %ignored
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=red,line legend] {0.1*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{graph 3} %ignored
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=blue,line legend] {0.0*x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option 2**

As suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel, you can define a new style by

```
\pgfplotsset{ignore legend/.style={every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}}}
```

in the preamble and now you can use your hypothetical `ignore legend` as you wished.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ignore legend/.style={every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend style = {at={(1.03,-0.03)}},
        ignore legend %hypothetical option! NOT ANYMORE
    ]
    \addlegendentry{graph 1} %ignored
    \addplot+[mark=none,fill=yellow,draw=none,forget plot] {0.1*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{graph 2} %ignored
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=red,line legend] {0.1*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{graph 3} %ignored
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=blue,line legend] {0.0*x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

As  **Christian Feuersänger** writes in his comment,

> It is save to overwrite this macro to no-operation. However, your
>   solution does not really overwrite it to no-operation, because it
>   results in \relax{graph 1} - and {graph 1} is still processed by TeX.
>   In your case, the characters are silently ignored... but if you write
>   complicated things in the argument, it might fail.

and his suggestion is to use

```
\pgfplotsset{ignore legend/.style={every axis legend/.code={\renewcommand\addlegendentry[2][]{}}}}
```

instead of

```
\pgfplotsset{ignore legend/.style={every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}}}
```

since *`\renewcommand` takes care of both the mandatory and the optional argument of `\addlegendentry`.*

**Option 3**

If you are freshly  writing the code, then simply omit the command `\addlegendentry{graph 3}` etc.

Comment: I'd go the whole nine yards and use `\pgfplotsset{ignore legend/.style={every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}}}` in the preamble so that the OP can use their “hypothetical” option `ignore legend`.

Comment: Note that this is a very questionable hack and might be breaking stuff :). I'd rather wait for Christian to approve since he knows it inside out.

Comment: @HarishKumar It is save to overwrite this macro to no-operation. However, your solution does not really overwrite it to no-operation, because it results in `\relax{graph 1}` - and `{graph 1}` is still processed by TeX. In your case, the characters are silently ignored... but if you write complicated things in the argument, it might fail.

Comment: @HarishKumar  In your case, it would work if you write `\renewcommand\addlegendentry[2][]{}` instead of `\let...\relax` because `\renewcommand` takes care of both the mandatory and the optional argument of `\addlegendentry`

Comment: As pointed out by @ChristianFeuersänger, the \relax can lead to unintentional stuff. I had probelms, just by having math symbols in my legend (which I consider pretty standard and nothing exotic), e.g., $\gamma=0.5$. The \renewcommand option is definitely the better one. I think you should remove the \relax solution entirely.

Comment: @christian-feuersänger this does not work for ``\addlegendentryexpanded``. The legend just hangs around in the bottom left corner. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 5):

What about typing `\legend{}` before `\end{axis}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this a follow-up question for clearification?

Comment: That works well.  You should expand this to be a complete answer, including a full minimal document demonstrating that it works.